# How to deal with a table that exists in the ALL_OBJECTS table but cannot be selected

Tags: oracle, table

I am seeing a weird behaviour in my Oracle DB schema around a 'missing' table.

The end goal is to gather statistics for all the tables that our team uses. All those tables have a common prefix - `rca`.

So, I am fetching the list of tables using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
where OBJECT_NAME like 'rca%' 
  AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

This query returns a table called `rca_related_materials`.

We're using a function developed by some other team that does the gather stats job for us. We just pass the owner_name and the table_name to that function.

Calling that function for this table name or running

```
analyze table rca_related_materials compute statistics for table;
```

or even,

```
select * 
from rca_related_materials;
```

returns the below Error report

```
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How can I get this entry removed from the ALL_OBJECTS table?

PS: I see the same entry coming up in USER_TABLES and DBA_TABLES also.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should not use `analyze table` any longer. That has been replaced by the package `dbms_stats` ages ago.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: We're actually using an internal function that does the job for us. We just pass the owner_name and the table_name to that function. Will update the question with this info.

Comment: As I said: that's unrelated to your current problem, so it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database objects with lowercase names need to have their name enclosed in double quotes when referenced

Also, you left out the schema name.

Try

```
select * 
from SCHEMA_NAME."rca_related_materials";
```